# mysql select first record based on date group by client

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, min

I have the following MySQL "appointments" table

```
id | date | notes | client_id
-----------------------------
10 | 2018-02-02 | test1 | 1015
11 | 2018-02-03 | test2 | 1016
12 | 2018-03-06 | test3 | 1015
13 | 2018-03-14 | test4 | 1015
14 | 2018-03-15 | test5 | 1016
```

I would like to display, within a date period I will search for, only the clients that during that period was their FIRST appointment.

So if I search for 2018-02-03 to 2018-02-07 it should only display client_id 1016 because client_id may have an appointment during that period but already had another record before that period (I do not care if any appointments follow after the period I search for).

I hope my description was clear. Thank you

Comment: for first appointment  you mean that have not an appointment before the min data of your range ??

Comment: @scaisEdge exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `appointments`
WHERE (date BETWEEN '2018-02-03' AND '2018-02-07')
group by client_id
order by date desc
```